# How to get powershell to output variable with quotes around it

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

Despite going over the documentation on single and double quotes using 'about_quoting_rules', I can't seem to get the output I'm looking for.

A little backstory:

I have an excel doc and I'm using powershell to create a foreach over every entry.  This, in turn, is being used to generate a robocopy command to kick off a sync job.

The part of my script that's pertinent to this is below:

```
Foreach($script in $roboSource)
{

    $StandardSwitches = "/copy:DAT /s /dcopy:DAT /V /L"
    $log = "/log:`"$($logPath)$($logFileName)`""                                                                                                #`
    $FileSource = "$($script.a)"
    $FileDestination = "$($script.a)"

    $RoboArgs = "I:\" + $FileSource + " " + "Z:\" + $FileDestination + " " + $StandardSwitches + " " + $log
}
```

So, right now,  $RoboArgs outputs this:

```
I:\XXXXX\XXXXX\X\XXXXXXX\XXXXX\XXXX Z:\XXXXX\XXXXX\X\XXXXXXX\XXXXX\XXXX /copy:DAT /s /dcopy:DAT /V /L /log:"C:\XXXXX\XXXXX\X\XXXXXXX\XXXXX\XXXX"
```

What I need $RoboArgs to output is this:

```
"I:\XXXXX\XXXXX\X\XXXXXXX\XXXXX\XXXX" "Z:\XXXXX\XXXXX\X\XXXXXXX\XXXXX\XXXX" /copy:DAT /s /dcopy:DAT /V /L /log:"C:\XXXXX\XXXXX\X\XXXXXXX\XXXXX\XXXX"
```

I've tried adding the backticks to the string, and encapsulating the string and variable together:

```
$RoboArgs = `""I:\" + $FileSource`"" + " " + "Z:\" + $FileDestination + " " + $StandardSwitches + " " + $log
```

But regardless of what I try, nothing is resulting in the output that I'm looking for.  Any nudge in the right direction would be very helpful and appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using PowerShell's [string-formatting operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators#format-operator--f), `-f`:

```
$RoboArgs = '"I:\{0}" "Z:\{1}" {2} {3} {4}' -f 
              $FileSource, $FileDestination, $StandardSwitches, $log
```

- Using `'...'` (single-quoting) as the delimiters allows you to embed `"` instances as-is.
- `{0}` is a placeholder for the 1st RHS operand, `{1}` for the 2nd, and so on.

Answer (score 4):

In Powershell `` ` `` followed by quotes works, like `'\'` in other languages:

For example:

```
"`"toto`""
```

prints

```
"toto"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try delimiting your string with single quotes. Any double qoutes inside will be preserved in the resulting string.

Example:

```
$stringWithQuotes = '"' + (pwd) + '"'
```

And you can also do it the other way around if you want single quotes in your string:

```
$stringWithQuotes = "'" + (pwd) + "'"
```